# Use backend branch when starting server on frontend branch

Tags: git

I don't know how to ask this question correctly. I have following case:

There are several branches in the project

- master

  - frontend

    - feature branch
  - backend

Frontend and backend branches are readonly, so is master. I'm working on frontend feature branch and starting npm server there, but I need it to use backend code from backend branch to check if requests work correctly etc. How do I do that?

Comment: How are `frontend` and `backend` different? If they're read-only, and they're the same repo, why do they exist?

Comment: @isherwood frontend branch contains tested frontend code and backend contains tested server code. I can work on feature branch only, when I'm done someone else merges it with the frontend branch. I just need to use backend branch code when starting npm server on my frontend feature branch.

Comment: I think what's really being asked is - why do you develop different parts of your code on different branches (rather than all on master)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm struggling to see the benefit of having separate testing or aggregation branches. Obviously the frontend and backend code changes need to work (and be tested) together. You can see the downside right here. Maybe propose a single `develop` branch workflow if you'd rather not commit to master (`git-flow` strategy).

Answer (score 1):

Just... merge in the backend branch.

> git fetch; git merge origin/backend

You can bring it into your branch if you're sure you'll stay upstream of production, or create a new branch for local testing.

> git checkout -b frontend-local-testing
>
> git fetch; git merge origin/backend

You can then checkout frontend to do more work and merge it into your local testing branch again later.

Believe it or not, you can work on multiple branches together with [git-worktree](https://www.elmund.io/2016/01/11/working-on-multiple-git-branches-simultaneously/). I've found that a bit cumbersome for my little brain, though, and prefer testing branches for my own sanity.